# Python Django saving two models from an html form

Tags: python, django, forms, save

I have two models: PersonelModel and ArizaModel. Both in one html form.
Personel data was previously saved in the PersonelModel table. When the fetch data button is pressed, the data is fetched by querying according to the p_sicil field. It is displayed in the p_isim and p_bilgisayar_adi fields. I created the required relationship between PersonelModel and ArizaModel.

I want to save the data I entered in the a_aciklama field into the database according to the relationship between PersonelModel and ArizaModel.

[Screenshot of html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXh4u.jpg)

How can i do that?

**models.py:**

```
class PersonelModel(models.Model):
    p_sicil = models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name='Personel Sicili')
    p_isim = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Personel Adı')
    p_bilgisayar_adi = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Bilgisayar Adı')
    p_durum = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Personel Durumu')
    birim = models.ForeignKey(BirimModel, verbose_name=("BİRİM"), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    grup = models.ForeignKey(GrupModel, verbose_name=("GRUP"), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    unvan = models.ForeignKey(UnvanModel, verbose_name=("ÜNVAN"), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'PersonelTablosu'
        verbose_name = "PERSONEL"
        verbose_name_plural = "PERSONELLER"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_sicil

class ArizaModel(models.Model):
    a_aciklama = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Arıza Açıklama')
    a_acilma_tarihi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Açılma Tarihi')
    a_durum = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Arıza Durumu')
    a_kapanma_tarihi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Kapanma Tarihi')
    birim = models.ForeignKey(BirimModel, verbose_name=("BİRİM"), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    teknik_personel = models.ForeignKey(TeknikPersonelModel, verbose_name=("TEKNİK PERSONEL"), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    personel_ariza_acan = models.ForeignKey(PersonelModel, verbose_name=("AÇAN PERSONEL"), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ArizaTablosu'
        verbose_name = "ARIZA"
        verbose_name_plural = "ARIZALAR"   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.a_aciklama
```

**forms.py:**

```
class PersonelBilgileriForm(forms.ModelForm):
    p_sicil = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'placeholder' : 'ab sicil',
        'maxlength' : '8'
    }))
    
    p_isim = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'placeholder' : 'Adınız Soyadınız',
        'maxlength' : '50'
    }))
    
    p_bilgisayar_adi = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'placeholder' : 'Bilgisayar adınızın son 4 hanesi',
        'maxlength' : '4'
    }))
    
    class Meta:
        model = PersonelModel
        fields = ['p_sicil','p_isim','p_bilgisayar_adi']
        
class ArizaBilgileriForm(forms.ModelForm):
    a_aciklama = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'placeholder' : 'Arızayı yazınız'
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = ArizaModel
        fields = ['a_aciklama']
```

**views.py:**

```
def kullaniciArizaKaydetView(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = ArizaBilgileriForm(request.POST, prefix='ariza_bilgileri')

        kullaniciningirdigisicil = request.POST['sicildenpersonelbulinput']

        try:
            personelbilgileri = PersonelModel.objects.get(p_sicil=kullaniciningirdigisicil)
            icerik = {'bulunanbilgi':kullaniciningirdigisicil, 'personelbilgileri':personelbilgileri, 'ArizaBilgileriForm': form2}
            return render(request, 'kullanici.html', icerik)
        except:
            return render(request, 'kullanici.html', {"hata":"kullanıcı tanımlı değil"})   
    else:
        return render(request, 'kullanici.html')
```

**kullanici.html: form area**

```
<form action="{% url 'kullaniciGetirURL' %}" method="POST" id="form-box" class="p-2">
          {% csrf_token %}

          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="search" class="form-control" value="{{personelbilgileri.p_sicil}}"  name="sicildenpersonelbulinput">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Kişisel Bilgileri Getir</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{personelbilgileri.p_isim}}" name="" readonly>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{personelbilgileri.p_bilgisayar_adi}}" name="" readonly>
          </div>

          {% if personelbilgileri %}
            <div class="form-group input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></span>
              </div>
              {{ArizaBilgileriForm.a_aciklama}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="ARIZA BİLDİR">
            </div>
          {% endif %}
</form>
```

How can I save it to the database after the information is entered in the form?

Comment: You can use `form2.save()` to save the form.

Comment: I couldn't find exactly where to write.

Comment: You have written the code in your native language, so its also not clear to me that from where you are sending the form, and where are the errors.

Comment: Can you please tell are you sending some errors in `except` part to the template, what is this key `hata`?

Comment: you're right. I am sorry. There is a form with information from two different models: Ariza Model and PersonelModel. There is onetomany relationship between them: ArizaModel => personel_ariza_acan = models.ForeignKey(PersonelModel). I want to save all the information on this form to the database at the same time